# How can I open info box of specific marker automatically in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to open an info box of a marker automatically by given marker's id.

```
//Data of markers are from JSON
var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
      id: place.id,
      map: map,
      title:place.title,
      icon : 'assets/frontend/images/marker.png'
    });
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infoWindow.open(map, markers);
```

For example, Assuming that I want to open info box of marker that has id = 243

```
var marker_id = 243;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `google-maps-utility-library-v3` for infobox, modify your code as following, if you have multiple markers and need multiple info box according to the markers, you can repeat the code for the `infobox`, first try for a single marker and you can have idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script language="javascript">
//Data of markers are from JSON
$(document).ready(function(){   
            /*Your map code needs to be here*/
            /*Marker being created below*/
    var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
          id: place.id,
          map: map,
          title:place.title,
          icon : 'assets/frontend/images/marker.png'
        });

    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
      boxText.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
      boxText.innerHTML = "Your map info here";
      var myOptions_txtbox = {
         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
        ,zIndex: null
        ,boxStyle: { 
          background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
          ,opacity: 0.75
          ,width: "280px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
            };
            /*Text box being created for marker `markers` */
    var infobox_new = new InfoBox(myOptions_txtbox);
            /*Created text box is assigned for marker `markers`. You can assign any event. For now, I have selected on `click` */
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers, "click", function (e) {
        infobox_new.open(map, this);
    });
});
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I want it to auto open, not by click event. Please advice.

Comment: I don't think you are going to open all info box for all markers at a time, so I added that click event, if you want to open all those, then just call the function, remove that addListener block and replace that by infobox_new.open(map, markers);

Comment: I just want to open the one with given id. Nothing less, nothing more.

Comment: But how can it know which info window of marker will be opened?
For example I want to open info window of marker id 243.