# Google Maps API open info box on href click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web app that shows all of the applications to work for my company. I would like to be able to click on the applicant names in the LI and have their info box pop up. I've tried using the openbox event, but that seems to only work as the map loads. How would I open the infobox with the link in the LI? would I use onclick() ?

[image: Screenshot of the app. Names have been cropped out]

Current Code:

```
  jQuery(function() {
    "use strict";

    // init map
    var map = new GMaps({
        div: '#applicantLocation',
        lat: 39,
        lng: -97,
        zoom: 4
    });

  map.drawCircle({
      lat: '.$staff_lat.',
      lng: '.$staff_lng.',
      radius: '.$meters.',
      fillColor: "#'.$hex.'",
      fillOpacity: 0.35
  });

  map.addMarker({
    lat: '.$staff_lat.',
    lng: '.$staff_lng.',
    title: "'.$row["firstName"].' '.$row["lastName"].'",
    infoWindow: {
      content:
      "<h4><a href=\'profile.php?a='.$row["vendorAppID"].'\'>'.$row["fName"].' '.$row["lName"].'</a></h4>"+
      "<p>'.$row["vendorType"].' from '.$row["city"].', '.$row["state"].'.</p>"+
      "<p>Applied '.$timeSince.'.</p>"
    }
  });
```

I've thought of using this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers, "click", function (e) {
        infobox_new.open(map, this);
    });
```

based on [How can I open info box of specific marker automatically in Google Maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207999/how-can-i-open-info-box-of-specific-marker-automatically-in-google-maps)

but I don't know how to adjust it so it works when I click on the LI on the left

Comment: try: echo array in php to json and javascript use it to parse into google map :) ..

Comment: @HoangHieu would you mind dumbing that down for me a bit?